# Polygons not containing other polygons

Tags: qgis, select-by-location

I have two large polygon data-sets, one highlights the building footprints and one indicating parcel outlines. I want to find all parcels without a building on them. Essentially all parcel A's which do not contain a parcel B. Is the Spatial query, select by location the best way to do this? The files are very large and often crash.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. If you have not done so, please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format. Please [edit] your question to detail what you have tried, and if you are seeing crashes, please include any crash messages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `Select by location` is the right tool. (In this example I used `Extract by location` but they are essentially the same).

To reduce QGIS' burden, we can:

1. Process data without showing the layers on the map canvas
2. Perform only one task at one time.

For example:

(1) Consider we want to extract `Parcel 103` (no buildings).

[image]

(2) Restart QGIS (or just remove all layers) to empty the map area.

(3) Activate `Extract by location` (under `Processing Toolbox | Vector selection tools`).

[image]

1. Click on the <kbd>...</kbd> button and select `parcel` data.
2. Click on the <kbd>...</kbd> button and select `buildings` data.
3. Select **disjoint** for the `Geometric predicate`.
4. Run the too..

(4) We will get new `Extracted` layer.

[image]

I echo [ThingumaBob](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/93656/thingumabob) that you may as well consider changing data provider.

Comment: +1 - I usually use any form of SQL over built in tools and finding non-intersections is a bit of a pain (e.g. using plain `ST_Disjoint` on two tables results in a cross product etc.); if QGIS handles that elegantly, better use this than my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @ThingumaBob ; SQL looks a swiss-army-knife, great tool when used by PostGIS guru (i mean, you). It is helpful for me (when i use virtual layer), too. Just recently i am having a hard time trying to work on virtual layers. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you could

- select all features of your polygon layer
- run an intersection filter via `Select by location` on selected features
- choose `Removing from current selection`

Main point:

If those files (shapefiles?) are large enough to crash QGIS, consider moving to *GeoPackage*, or PostGIS even.